# Wordpress theme character encoding issue

Tags: encoding

I have set up nulled wordpress template with few functions and loops.Everything worked fine on localhost and hosting services. But i have got different charset while activating theme . The default themes are working fine. I have no other settings in wordpress changing character encoding and my database config is utf8 too.

```
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4');

define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

The wp-admin panel is displaying different charset too(latin else).Can you assist in this issue or advice?

Comment: What specifically is the symptom of this problem? Can you rule out a font issue?

Comment: i tried changing the character encoding 3 temis resaving document and refreshing it. I think the server admin spoted and fixed the issue. However all files were in ut8 encoding. So it is really camefrom unknown and dissapeared. Thanks for the watching it out.

Comment: Font issue..What do you mean?